# Get Google Analytics data source uploads with API

Tags: api, google-analytics, data-import

Is it possible to get data from Google Analytics data source via API with a given id?

I use `uploadData` to upload data to GA: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/uploads/uploadData

After uploading i get some response like `accountId`, `customDataSourceId`, `id`, `status` and `uploadTime`. With this information i want to grab informations from GA to use it for a end to end test.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that the upload itself went well, you can use the [`List` method from the management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/uploads/list).

If you want to check that data you uploaded is properly being mapped inside GA, you should use the [reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) and query for whichever dimensions you uploaded.